# limit $\lim_{n\to ∞}\sin(\pi(2+\sqrt3)^n)$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n\to ∞}\sin(\pi(2+\sqrt3)^n)$

I tried to write it as $\sin (n\pi - \theta)$ to get the form $∞-∞$ form within $\sin$ function. But could not proceed after that. How should I do it?

Edit:I am sorry, I forgot to mention $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: An idea (haven't pursued the line of reasoning further): Maybe rewriting $(2+\sqrt{3})^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} 2^{n-k} \sqrt{3}^k$ and splitting the sum depending on the parity of $k$ may help.

Comment: Does it even exist?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think $\{n\sqrt{3}\}$ (the fractional part) fluctuates on $(0,1)$. This might lead a divergent sequence here.

Comment: Well it turns out it does exist :)

Comment: @Dr.MV Doesn't it also require that $\left|(k-\sqrt{l})\right| < 1$? $k^2 > l$ is not enough to guarantee that.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Note $|2-\sqrt{3}|<1$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}(2-\sqrt{3})^n=0$. 
Since $(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n$ is an integer, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin[\pi(2+\sqrt{3})^n]\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\bigg[\pi\big[(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n\big]-\pi(2-\sqrt{3})^n\bigg]\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg\{\sin\bigg[\pi\big[(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n\big]\bigg]\cos\big[\pi(2-\sqrt{3})^n\big]\\
&&-\cos\bigg[\pi\big[(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n\big]\bigg]\sin\big[\pi(2-\sqrt{3})^n\big]\bigg\}\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: (+1) This is interesting! The function looks like fluctuating but apparently it is not.

Comment: Then how do you explain the graph?!?!?!?  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cmsnuraqfr

Comment: @SimpleArt restrict $x$ to be an integer.

Comment: @SimpleArt You can replace $x$ with $\operatorname{floor}(x)$, as YoTengoUnLCD says. However that makes a diverging graph too, for $x$ greater than twenty-something, apparently due to a limited precision of power calculation. Which makes your answer a good example why experimental methods (graphs among them) do not work as proofs in mathematics.

Comment: @SimpleArt Anytime when $n$ is used as a variable, it is quietly assumed that we are dealing with integer inputs...

Comment: This is confusing because the function does not converge over the reals, but it does converge over the integers.

Comment: @user3294068 Well, different properties for the integers, different simplifications and all.

Answer (score 26):

**Hint(s)**: $(2+\sqrt{3})^n$ is closer and closer to an integer as $n$ increases, since
$$ (2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n $$
is an integer and $|2-\sqrt{3}|<\frac{1}{3}$. The sine function is a Lipschitz-continuous function and $\sin(\pi m)=0$ for any integer $m$, hence your limit equals zero.

Answer (score 10):

since 
$$
K(n)=(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n \in \mathbf{N}
$$
$$\lim_{n\to ∞}(2-\sqrt3)^n=0$$
You can do the following:
$$\lim_{n\to ∞}\sin(\pi(2+\sqrt3)^n)=\lim_{n\to ∞}\sin(\pi(K(n)-(2-\sqrt3)^n))=-\lim_{n\to ∞}\sin(\pi(2-\sqrt3)^n)=0
$$